# Column marging on a WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I created a grid. On this grid, i have two colums with two TextBlock
I would like to insert a space between my columns, in order to having space between my textBlocks.

How doing this ?

Here is my code :

```
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxTiers" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0"> 
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Grid Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition />                                           
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="TxtBox_CodeTiers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strCode}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TxtBox_NomTiers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strNom}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of playing with the columnns, set a margin around the textbox.

```
<TextBox Margin="10">
```

You can set each side independently or set left/right and up/down:

```
<TextBox Margin="10, 3, 7, 0">
<TextBox Margin="10, 5">
```

Or wrap your TextBoxes inside another panel and set the margin there:

```
<Grid Margin="10">
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes but i need to do these for each TextBox. I would like to set a margin once !

Comment: You can apply a style on all similar controls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569974/wpf-global-style or you can also wrap your textboxes into another panel, such as a `Grid`, and set the margin of the `Grid`. You would need one Grid per column or "groups" of controls. I edited my answer with the Grid idea.

Comment: Walter, did you know you need to accept the answers that worked for you by using the checkmark button? If my answer is  not sufficient, let me know how I can help you further.