# Can I create a single style or data trigger for 50 WPF Labels that changes background color depending on view model boolean values

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, label

I have a requirement to display around 50 Labels that would change background color depending on the value of a view model boolean property. Each Label is associated with a different view model boolean property.  How can I create a single style to do this that I can associate with all 50 labels, so that I don't have to declare a style for every label.  Is there a way I can apply a SINGLE style and/or data trigger to ALL 50 labels, since each label will be bound to a different view model boolean property.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569974/wpf-global-style

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF - Global Style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569974/wpf-global-style)

Comment: I am well aware of how global styles work.  My SPECIFIC question: is there a way I can apply a SINGLE style or data trigger to ALL 50 labels, since each label will be bound to a different view model boolean property.

Comment: You don't need a Style. Just directly bind a Label's Background property to the appropriate view model property with a binding converter. Besides that, you may create an attached property that holds the source property path, and create an appropriate Binding in code behind.

Comment: Thanks mucho!! Your answer will save me a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am well aware of how global styles work. My SPECIFIC question: is there a way I can apply a SINGLE style or data trigger to ALL 50 labels, since each label will be bound to a different view model boolean property.

No. You cannot dynamically change the binding of a `DataTrigger` unless you create it programmatically.

I am afraid there is no way to dynamically just replace the binding path of a `DataTrigger` and re-use the rest of the style or template in XAML.

Comment: Thanks ... I was just wanting to make sure that there wasn't a way that I could do this before applying a different data trigger to 50 different labels.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can try to create a custom Template for the Labels and add ControlTemplate trigger to change the background of label.

```html
<Style x:Key="test" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="test"></TextBlock>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColorValue}" Value="12">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aquamarine"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Above code is just to show the usage, it is not the exact answer.

Comment: I think this would work if all 50 labels were bound to the same view model boolean property .. HOWEVER ... each label is bound to its own separate boolean property.

Comment: Totally agree with your point, Howeverm I think if each viewmodel has same property name this should work. Let me try it. I guess if we can have a base viewmodel with the property and make sure each viewmodel uses that property for that label. let me know if you think otherwise.